# How to create powershell script dynamically from c# based on input params without having physical script file in machine

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, asp.net-core

I know we can can run physical powershell script from c# but how to create powershell script file itself dynamically based on input params.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute powershell script/ commands directly from your c# project.
you'll need to add a reference to **system.managment.automation** dll in project's references.

example:
function that will take script as a string , execute it and then returns a result:

```
private string RunScript(string script)
{
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipline.Commands.AddScript(script);
    pipline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipline.Invoke();
    runspace.Close();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(PSObject pSObject in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

function call be like:

```
Console.WriteLine(RunScript("Your Powershell Script"));
```

you can check out the full code examples on [github - PowershellCommand-CSharp](https://github.com/Asadblum/PowershellCommands-CSharp)